# Redirect startActivity to renamed activity package

Tags: android

I'm designing 2 applications (A and B) that communicate using intents.

In application A, I recently renamed the package of an activity that is started by application B using "startActivity".

The problem is that, when I'll deploy the new version, if clients update application A without updating application B, application B will crash when trying to start the activity using the old package name.

How can I solve this problem ? Is there a way to redirect (in the manifest maybe ?) the old package name to the new ?

Comment: How about catching the exception and using the old packagename as a fallback?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Easiest thing would be to include the old package in your new release as well. Then code that old activity to redirect to your new one for now. You can have multiple package namespaces in your project.

Comment: Yes it works. I created a class with the same name in the old package that does nothing than "startactivity(newpackage); finish" in the onCreate method. Thx